# How do I pass the "img" object to an onload event handler in ReactJS JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an `img` tag that i want to listen to the `onLoad` event for, but I also need the actual image object so i can check width/height, etc on it. These are created dynamically, so I can't know the id beforehand.

```
//In the JSX:
<img src={this.generateSrc(config)} onLoad={this.handleOnLoad} />
```

In normal javascript, I could do:

```
<img onload="someFunction(this)" />
```

How do I pass that in ReactJS?

Answer (score 2):

You could get actual image object via `e.target`.

```
handleOnLoad(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Or via [Refs to Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

```
handleOnLoad() {
    console.log(this.refs.img);
}

<img ref='img' src={this.generateSrc(config)} onLoad={this.handleOnLoad.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Safari and Firefox don't pass an event to that callback

Comment: @DonRhummy, sorry I didn't test that. Or you could set a `ref` in `img` and retrieve it via `this.refs.img`

Comment: it creates hundreds of them dynamically, not just one

Comment: not true, safari and firefox both register the target of the onload event of an image

Answer (score 0):

future javascript allows you to do:

```
handleOnLoad = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
}

<img src={imgSrc} onLoad={this.handleOnLoad} />
```